# C: void pointer to struct member of type char[]

Tags: c, struct, string-comparison, void-pointers, qsort

I have this class

```
struct person {
    char name[100];
    int age
};
```

and then this array:

```
struct student people[] = { {"bill", 30}, {"john", 20}, {"bob", 11} };
```

I then want to write a function that I can pass to `qsort`; a function like this:

```
int compare_name(const void *a, const void *b);
```

Normally, when for example having an array of string like this

```
char names[5][10] = { "xxx", "uuu", "ccc", "aaa", "bbb" };
```

I would be able to work with the  `const void * a` and `const void *b`  like this:

```
int compare_name(const void *a, const void *b) {
    for (; *( char*)a == *(char *)b; a++, b++)
        if (*(char *)a == '\0') return 0;
    return *(char *)a - *(char *)b;
```

But how do I write the same method, that is how do I tell C that the void pointer is referring to the field `name` of the `struct person` if I want to sort the array according to alphabetical order?

Eventually, I would need to be able to call `qsort` like this:

```
int npeople = sizeof(class) / sizeof(struct student);
qsort(people, npeople, sizeof(struct person), compare_name);
```

But as said, I am not able to turn `const void *a`  into the needed value (`person->name`) like I did with `*( char*)a` when simply working with an array of strings.

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: struct person and struct student are different structures.

Comment: You don't; you have the pointers be to the things you want to compare (the `struct`s), and the comparison function knows *how* to do the comparison (in this case, by comparing the `name` fields of those `struct`s).

Comment: Yeah sorry, struct student people[] should have been struct person people[]; if someone can edit it, it would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have this class

```
 struct person {
     char name[100];
     int age };
```

> and then this array:

```
struct student people[] = { {"bill", 30}, {"john", 20}, {"bob", 11} };
```

There are many typos in your code as for example `struct person` and `struct student` are different type specifiers. And there are no classes in C opposite to C++.

Nevertheless the comparison function can look the following way

```
#include <string.h>

//...

int compare_name( const void *a, const void *b )
{
    const struct person *p1 = a;
    const struct person *p2 = b;

    return strcmp( p1->name, p2->name );
}
```

Also pay attention to that increment operations like this `a++, b++` are not defined for pointers of the type `c/v void *` though some compilers can have their own language extensions that contradict the C Standard..

Comment: Yeah sorry, ```struct student people[]``` should have been ```struct person people[]```. 

I see and it makes sense, thanks!

Comment: Also, I did not know that "to that increment operations like this a++, b++ are not defined for pointers of the type c/v void *", this also and additionally explains why my previous code was not working too well.